# Mysql table scheme for featured / emphasized products

Tags: mysql, product, database-schema

Well my problem is that I would like to **store some kind of products** in their own tables and **from these products** I would like to select some **into a featured / emphasised products table** which would store the ID of the selected rows from each table to display those featured products on the home page of a website.

After selecting the featured products from their tables I would like to make my own order how they will be listed, so I think a new table is needed where I can store the ID and the order of the featured products, but I can't imagine how to connect these tables properly.

I was thinking a lot how to solve this problem but, I hope somebody will know the correct answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a second table:

```
CREATE TABLE FEATURED_PRODUCTS (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRODUCT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRODUCT_ORDER INTEGER NOT NULL
)
```

Then just join with your original table when you want to find your featured products:

```
SELECT P.*
FROM PRODUCTS P 
    INNER JOIN FEATURED_PRODUCTS FP ON P.ID = FP.PRODUCT_ID
ORDER BY FP.PRODUCT_ORDER
```

Its probably worth stating that ID in the FEATURED_PRODUCTS table is not strictly necessary, I just don't like having tables without primary key columns.

**---- EDIT ----**

More complete example:

```
CREATE TABLE FRUIT_PRODUCTS (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(255),
    PRICE INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FARM_OF_ORIGIN VARCHAR(255)
)

CREATE TABLE BREAD_PRODUCTS (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(255),
    PRICE INTEGER NOT NULL,
    TYPE_OF_GRAIN VARCHAR(255)
)

CREATE TABLE MEAT_PRODUCTS (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(255),
    PRICE INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ANIMAL VARCHAR(255)
)

CREATE TABLE FEATURED_PRODUCTS (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(255),
    PRODUCT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRODUCT_ORDER INTEGER NOT NULL
)
```

Then you could join them all thusly:

```
SELECT FP.TABLE_NAME, P.ID, P.NAME, P.PRICE, P.FARM_OF_ORIGIN, 
    NULL AS TYPE_OF_GRAIN, NULL AS ANIMAL
FROM FEATURED_PRODUCTS FP 
    INNER JOIN FRUIT_PRODUCTS P ON FP.TABLE_NAME = 'FRUIT_PRODUCTS' 
        AND FP.PRODUCT_ID = P.ID
UNION
SELECT FP.TABLE_NAME, P.ID, P.NAME, P.PRICE, NULL AS FARM_OF_ORIGIN, 
    P.TYPE_OF_GRAIN, NULL AS ANIMAL
FROM FEATURED_PRODUCTS FP 
    INNER JOIN BREAD_PRODUCTS P ON FP.TABLE_NAME = 'BREAD_PRODUCTS' 
        AND FP.PRODUCT_ID = P.ID
UNION
SELECT FP.TABLE_NAME, P.ID, P.NAME, P.PRICE, NULL AS FARM_OF_ORIGIN, 
    NULL AS TYPE_OF_GRAIN, P.ANIMAL
FROM FEATURED_PRODUCTS FP 
    INNER JOIN MEAT_PRODUCTS P ON FP.TABLE_NAME = 'MEAT_PRODUCTS' 
        AND FP.PRODUCT_ID = P.ID
```

Which would give you a result set containing all the featured products.  *Note that this is untested, but should get the idea across*.

Comment: . . `order` is a lousy name for a column because it is a MySQL reserved word.

Comment: Yes this is good for one type of products, but I have 3 type of products and you can't join 3 tables to another on one column. Or maybe should I create columns to every table to join them to the featured products table?

Comment: Where are you storing the type id... against the product, if so simply select for only that product type and that should split up your results into the 3 types...

Comment: Well now I have 3 tables. Each table has id, name, description, price columns and some other different columns. I don't know if this is correct, probably I should have stored the data in one table, but then how could I store the unique things for a type of product..

Comment: @user2042930, one table would probably be best, but you can use this approach against 3 tables, just dont make PRODUCT_ID a foreign key.  Then use UNION to get the union of the joins against all 3 tables.  Not recommended, but you could do it...

Comment: Could you send an example please? I am not sure if that would work, because there can be PRODUCT_ID 1 in all the 3 tables, so I should have an additional column to distinguish which table the PRODUCT_ID belongs to. By the way I am not against changing my existing scheme. Maybe there would be cool to have a main table and 3 other specialization of it with the unique columns of the product types. But I don't know how could I select the data of the products then. I think there would be needed an additional column in the main table for that to work.

Comment: @user2042930, See the edit above offering a more complete example.

Comment: This seems to be good! Thanks! By the way I think this may be the faster query, but I would like to be sure that the query with LEFT joins without UNIONs is slower, right? I mean this: SELECT ... ((FROM FP LEFT JOIN MP ON FP.table = 'meat' AND FP.id = MP.id) LEFT JOIN BP ON FP.table = 'bread' AND BP.id = FP.id).

Comment: @user2042930, you could try that, though not sure it will work due to the columns not in common among the 3 product tables.